# placeholder visible always false

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, placeholder

I have a placeholder inside updatepanel, thats also inside a placeholder and an updatepanel. However, according to my tests this layout shouldnt matter on this error. My placeholder always have visible set to false, even if I try to set it to true. I have tried to step thought the code, and the code for setting the placeholder to true is running. Yet, it doesnt set it to true.

```
myPlaceholder.Visible = true;

if(myPlaceholder.Visible)  
//Do stuff inside placeholder

myUpdatePanel.Update();
```

This only happens on the first load tho, on postbacks myPlaceholder visible sets to true. Its probably something else in the web application thats wrong and creates this error, but its so big I dont know where to start looking. My hope is that someone had a similar problem that can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is parent of myPlaceholder control visible ?

Comment: It seems to be a connection. I set the parent placeholder to visible first after the myPlaceholder is supposed to be set to true. I did try this on a test page and then it worked. But now i tried to set the parent placeholder to visible just before setting myPlaceholder to visible and now it shows.

Comment: 1000 thanks. Wow, this was driving me crazy. I had code setting various placeholders in a usercontrol visible based on conditions and then would set the user control visible. Turns out, if the placeholder's parent (in this case my usercontrol) is not visible, setting the placeholder to visible=true does nothing. Who knew? Thanks again.